# inputing rails erb syntax into bootstrap 4 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, syntax, erb

I am trying to implement this rails generated form into a bootstrap form I have found and can't figure out the proper syntax to get it to look/work right.

this is the rails erb syntax

```
    <%= form_tag users_sessions_path do %>

            <%= label_tag :email %>
            <%= text_field_tag :email %>
        <p>
            <%= label_tag :password %>
            <%= password_field_tag :password %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= submit_tag 'Log In' %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

and this is the bootstrap form

```
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You should really consult with [RoR api documents](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

```
<%= form_tag users_sessions_path do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :email, 'Email address' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'form-control', id: 'exampleInputEmail1', placeholder: 'Email' %>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: 'form-control', id: 'exampleInputPassword1', placeholder: 'Password' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, true, false, class: 'form-check-input' %>
      Check me out
    </label>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the ERB `<%= form_tag %>` , `<%= label_tag %>` , etc. are helpers to create the HTML `<form>` and `<label>` tags (hence the ERB name)

Changing your Boostrap form into ERB is as simple as copying over the div's and classes/ids

```
<%= form_tag users_sessions_path do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email,  class: 'form-control', 
                                id: 'exampleInputEmail1', 
                                aria-describedby: 'emailHelp',
                                placeholder: 'Email' %>
  </div>

<!-- Continue with the rest of your code -->

<% end %>
```